# python tornado - how to return real-time data

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I am using the tornado library in python. I have a queue where data gets added in. I have to keep connection open so that when client requests I send out items from queue. Here is a simple implementation of mine. The problem I face is when I add new elements to `queue`, I don't see it being it returned. Infact, I don't see any code executed below `IOLoop.current().start()` line.

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, Application, url,asynchronous
from Queue import Queue

import json

q=Queue()
q.put("one")
q.put("two")

class HelloHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        data=q.get()
        self.write(data)

def make_app():
     return Application([
         url(r"/", HelloHandler),
         ])

def main():
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    IOLoop.current().start() # stops here
    time.sleep(2)
    q.put("three")
    print q

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

first time on this :
http://localhost:8888/

returns "one"

second time on this:

http://localhost:8888/

return "two"

Third time on this"

http://localhost:8888/

blocking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that calling IOLoop.current().start() transfers control to Tornado. It loops until [IOLoop.stop()](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.stop) is called.

If you need to do something after the IOLoop has started, then you can use one of the callbacks. For example, here is your code modified to use [IOLoop.call_later()](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.call_later). You could also use [IOLoop.add_timeout()](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_timeout) if you are using an earlier (<4.0) version of Tornado.

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, Application, url,asynchronous
from Queue import Queue

import json

q=Queue()
q.put("one")
q.put("two")

class HelloHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        data=q.get()
        self.write(data)

def make_app():
     return Application([
         url(r"/", HelloHandler),
         ])

def main():
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    IOLoop.current().call_later(2, q.put, "three")
    IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```